# How to disable the Internet connection for a specific website?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, offline, offlineapps

I need to use a website to draw some diagrams, but I want to be sure that nothing goes to the server while I'm using it. This is why I want to use it locally.

After I visit that website, how can I **disable** the **Internet** connection only for that website in a given browser (I prefer Chrome, but I can also use Firefox or Internet Explorer)?

The website provides an "offline web application" containing:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
</html>
```

so, it will work **"offline"**. But this **doesn't avoid** the whole **communication** between the **client** and the **server** when the Internet connection is available. Using the Network tab I confirmed this "theoretical knowledge".

I don't want to stop the "whole" Internet connection, because I'd like to use other websites while drawing those diagrams.

Comment: "I suppose that this doesn't avoid the communication ..." Perhaps you should make some research in the codebase/net traffic before assuming?

Comment: @Teemu I edited the post. I converted the supposition into a fact.

Answer (score 0):

Either edit your etc/hosts to resolve the hostname of the website in question to 127.0.0.1 or install some blocker extension like [request policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%C2%B5matrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en) or [µmatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%C2%B5matrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en)